# How to take all elements from an array?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

When the user enters a name in the field, it is added to the array. How can I write all the elements to an array and output them to the console?

```js
const userNameInput = document.getElementById("user-name");
const userButton = document.getElementById("add-user");
const usersArr = [];

userButton.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  checkUserName();
  if (checkUserName()) {
    addUser();
  }
});

const addUser = () => {
  usersArr.push(userNameInput.value);
  clearInputs();
};


const getAllUsers = () => {
  usersArr.forEach((user) => {
    console.log(user);
  });
};

getAllUsers();
```

Comment: In what way is the code shown not working as expected?  When you debug, which specific operation fails?  Can you update this to a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: The user from the usersArr array is not displayed in the console

Comment: (1) The code shown is incomplete and won't run at all, producing console errors.  Have you checked the console for errors?  (2) If the actual code you're using does run successfully, you're calling `getAllUsers` *immediately* when the page loads.  If you're expecting it to print to the console data which hasn't been entered yet then I'm afraid that expectation is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Users array is initially empty. When script is executed it is evaluated line by line. You declare empty array in line 3, attach event listener in line 5 and call function getAllUsers at the end of script. It is called only once right after script is executed. What happens inside event handler is asynchronous action.